# Change O365 Password from Android Phone

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords, android

What is the best way to change a Microsoft O365 account password from an Android Phone?

I assume the user can log into Office 365 on the phone's Web browser, and the follow the steps on [www.office.com](http://www.office.com) to change the password there, but I wasn't sure if the Outlook app provided an easier method for users to change their passwords from the phone.

This is for employees that do not have company laptops, and only have accounts to access O365 email on their phones.  Hence the reason we need them to change their passwords from their phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experience, there may be no option that could change the password directly in Outlook for Android and I have voted this similar idea in Outlook uservoice:
https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/10325154-change-password
Hope it would come soon.